# Questions about obstruction theory (Hatcher's book)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration, obstruction-theory

I'm actually studying obstruction theory as presented in the last section of chapter $4$ of the book Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher.  He first finds condition so that a space $X$ admits a Postnikov tower of principal fibrations, which is a Postnikov tower

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\vdots & & \vdots\\
@| & @VVV       \\
X @>>> X_3 \\
@| & @VVV       \\
X @>>> X_2\\
@| & @VVV\\
X @>>> X_1
\end{CD}
where any map $ X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1}$ is such that exists a fibration sequence $F\rightarrow E\rightarrow B$ and weak homotopy equivalences $X_n\rightarrow F$ and $X_{n-1}\rightarrow E$ such that

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X_n @>>> X_{n-1} \\
 @VVV & @VVV    \\
F @>>> E@>>> B\\
\end{CD}
commutes.
The problem is that when a few pages later he deals with the problem of finding a map $W\rightarrow X_n$ to complete the commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>>> X_n \\
@VVV & @VVV       \\
W @>>> X_{n-1}\\
\end{CD}
where $(W,A)$ is a $CW$ pair and $A\rightarrow W$ is the inclusion, he supposes that $X_n$ actually is the pullback of the path fibration $PB\rightarrow B$ via $X_{n-1}\rightarrow B$.
Why can he suppose this?

Comment: The assertion is basically that if $E\to B$ is a fibration with fiber $F$, and if $PB\to B$ is a fibration such that the space $PB$ is contractible, then the space $E\times_BPB$ is equivalent to $F$. This is so because it fibers over the contractible space $PB$ with fiber $F$.

Comment: That's ok but it seems to me that in this way, trying to adapt what the Hatcher does, I can only deduce a map that makes the diagram commute up to homotopy. Anyway I need it to strictly commute, and even using the fact that the map $A\rightarrow W$ is a cofibration and the map $X_n\rightarrow X_{n-1}$ is a fibration it's not clear to me how to obtain a map $W\rightarrow X_n$ that makes the diagram commute.

Comment: If $A\to W$ is a cofibration and $X_n\to X_{n-1}$ is a fibration, then a solution up to homotopy should imply a strict solution.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know how to show.

Comment: This was also posted in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944664/doubts-on-obstruction-theory-hatchers-book).